# Java Algorithm regarding taking array of String and Integers to

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm

I'm currently doing an activity that requires me to write this:

> Write a definition for a static method stringHeads that inputs an array of ints p and a String s. For each of the ints n in p, the method builds the substring consisting of the first n characters in s (or the whole of s, if n is greater than the length of s). The method returns the array of these substrings.

My code is currently something like this:

```
public static String[] stringHeads(int[] p, String s) {
    String[] rad = new String[p.length];
    int e = 0;
    for (int b : p)
        e = b - 1
    for (int de = 0; rad.length > de; de++)
        rad[de] = s.substring(0,e);
    for (String str : rad)
        return str;
} 

//Just ignore the rest
int[] a = {4, 2, 3, 2, 0 };
String b = "Radon"
stringHeads(a,b)
```

The output should be "Rado" , "Ra", "Rad", "Ra", "".

The error that I'm currently getting is that String cannot be converted to String[].

Basically my question is how to fix this error and if a better code can be written.

Comment: Your return type of stringHeads() is String[] but you are returning string. You should pass the complete the string array completely.

Comment: `return rad` .......

Comment: replace `return str;` with `return rad;`. Remove the last loop.

Comment: Your error is being caused because it expects the return type to be `String[]`, but instead you attempt to iterate through `rad` and return each `String str` separately (which wouldn't work anyway since the method terminates after the first `return` statement reached). You should be able to use `return rad;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify you code by just using a single iteration with an alternative variable.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int[] a = {4, 2, 3, 2, 0 };
    String b = "Radon";
    String[] result = stringHeads(a,b);
    for(String x : result) System.out.println(x);
    //Or you can write a separate display method instead.
}
public static String[] stringHeads(int[] p, String s) 
{

    String[] rad = new String[p.length];
    //Use this variable for array allocation/iteration.
    int i=0;
    //Simply iterate using this for-each loop.
    // This takes care of array allocation/ substring creation.
    for (int x : p)
        rad[i++] = s.substring(0,x);
    return rad; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I felt like yours was the easiest to understand for me, also, I needed not to go over the index if x was greater than the length of s so I did: public static String[] stringHeads(int[] p, String s) {
String[] rad = new String[p.length]; 
int i = 0;
for (int x : p) {
if (x > s.length()) {
    rad[i++] = s;
}
else
rad[i++] = s.substring(0, x);
}
return rad;
}

Comment: Yeah, that would do good, and you're welcome, I'm more than happy to help :D

Answer (score 2):

Three things:

- e would be constant if you enter the second loop.
- e could be larger than s.length() - you didn't handle this case.
- You return a String instead of a String[]

And please always use braces if you use loops, even if the loop only contains one statement. It is much more readable and can avoid errors.

I think you will have to rethink your whole function. Don't know if it would be helpful to write the function for you.

Hints:
Write only one loop!

```
String[] rad = new String[p.length];
for (int i=0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (s.length() < ??) {
        rad[i] = s.substring(0,??);
    } else {
        ??
    }
}
return rad;
```

I hope this will help you to get the answer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

See my code below hope it helps:-
I provided the comments instead of explaining it in paragraph.
As for your error, you are returning String from method but expected is an array of String.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

       int[] a = {4, 2, 3, 2, 0 };
       String b = "Radon";
       String[] output=stringHeads(a,b);
       for(String s:output){
           System.out.println(s);
       }
   }
```

Your method can be like below:

```
public static String[] stringHeads(int[] p, String s) {
    String[] rad = new String[p.length];
    int e = 0;
    //Iterate over integer array
    for(int index=0; index<p.length; index++){
       //Extracting the integer value from array one by one
       e=p[index];
       //If integer value is greater than String length
       if(e>s.length()){
           //Put the entire String in String array
           rad[index]=s;
       }else{
           //Put the Substring value with range 0 to e i.e. integer value
           rad[index]=s.substring(0,e);
       }
    }
    return rad;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, this would be the whole function, exactly as I wrote it down before.
`index<p.length-1` is wrong. Shouldn't it be `index<p.length`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the for loop that iterates through the integer array p

```
public static String[] stringHeads(int[] p, String s) {
    String[] rad = new String[p.length];
    for (int de = 0; de < p.length; de++){
        if (p[de] < s.length())
            rad[de] = s.substring(0,p[de]);
        else
            rad[de]=s;
    }
    return rad;
}
```

Comment: Your answer  ignores that `p[de]` could be larger than `s.length()` .

Comment: Why leave `int e` in if it's no longer being used? Not to mention it's nearly identical to JornBuitink's answer (other than allowing the OP to work out a few parts on their own)

Comment: the int e was a mistake I had overlooked ,... Edited it much before you posted that comment ... I guess you didnt refresh the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below

public static String[] stringHeads(int[] intArray, String str) {

```
    String[] result = new String[intArray.length];
            int count=0;
    for (int intValue : intArray)

        {       

        result[count] = str.substring(0,intValue);
        count++;
        }
    return result;
    } //Just ignore the rest

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {4, 2, 3, 2, 0 };
        String b = "Radon";
        String[] strArray=stringHeads(a,b);
        int count=0;
        for(String str:strArray)
            System.out.println(++count+"" +str);        
    }
```

Comment: You should consider fixing your code indentation. The first line of code was excluded from the code block

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like this

```
public static String[] stringHeads(int[] p, String s) {
        String[] rad = new String[p.length];
        int e = 0;
        for (int b : p) {
            rad[e] = s.substring(0, b);
            e++;
        }


        return rad;
    }
```

For  use this method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = {4, 2, 3, 2, 0};
        String b = "Radon";
        String[] stringHeads = stringHeads(a, b);

        for (String stringHead : stringHeads) {
            System.out.println(stringHead);
        }
    }
```

Output is

```
Rado
Ra
Rad
Ra
```

Comment: Your answer  ignores that `b` could be larger than `s.length()` .

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] stringHeads(int[] p, String s) {
        String[] rad = new String[p.length];
        int e = 0;
        for (int b : p) {
            if(b<=s.length()){
            rad[e] = s.substring(0, b);

            }
                 e++;
        }


        return rad;
    }
```